# How to read the parameters of URL in oracle form

Tags: oracle, forms

I am using Oracle form 10
I want to know how can I access the parameters of URL in oracle form

Ex:
whenever I run the form it opens in a browser and the URL for the same is

http://112.10.0.10:7778/forms/frmservlet?config=pkamble

I just want to know how can I access the value of 'config' parameter inside oracle form code.

when we run oracle form using 10g then

I will appreciate the help !!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can read config parameter, but to read another parameter from URL your URL have to be like:

```
http://112.10.0.10:7778/forms/frmservlet?config=pkamble&otherparams=name=value
```

In your .fmb you will have to add 'name' parameter in the parameters block and then you could do something like:

```
if :PARAMETER.name = 'value' then
 message('ok');
end if;
```

And for more than one parameter use:

```
http://112.10.0.10:7778/forms/frmservlet?otherparams=name1=value1+name2=value2+name3=value3
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying assign the inbuilt variable config to the parameter 
but actualy you have to name the parameter like

http://112.10.0.10:7778/forms/frmservlet?config=pkamble&otherparams=confing1=pkamble

if you want to use the predefine paramater then user get_application_property inbult function by oracle