# Read POST data from Oracle Forms App

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am trying to receive some http POST data in my Oracle Forms app. How can I read this sent POST parameters from my Forms app?

Note: To read http-GET Data I use otherparams like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/340000/247684), but is fundamental to send data via POST http method

Comment: In forms there is no difference if parameters are send by HTTP GET or POST. Is your HTML form posting the parameters with the right enctype? Try application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: I create the form DOM-node via Javascript, then I execute a form.submit to send parameters via POST Method. What I have not tested yet is to send an "otherparams" (follow the link in my question note) parameter to check if my forms app receive it as if this was sent via url GET parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Efectively as [@Christian13467](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150629/christian13467) mentioned, for Oracle Forms is very indifferent how HTTP vars were sent, that is using POST or GET Methods.

My solution was to build an string containing all my vars concatenated as in **otherparams** format, then send it via POST Method. As my first form was contained into another Oracle Forms app, I edited a template file called **basejpi.htm**, to add a header javascript section with this code:

```
function sendPostVars(path,params) {
  var method = "post"; 

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "post");
  form.setAttribute("action", path);

  var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "otherparams");
  hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params);

  form.appendChild(hiddenField);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Then from my first Forms app I called this method via 11g javascript integration function like this:

```
web.javascript_eval_expr(sendPostVars('http://host2:port/forms/frmservlet','name1=param1+name2=param2'))
```

Finally I got my parameters read into my second Oracle Forms app.