# Call oracle forms from JavaScript by post method

Tags: javascript, forms, oracle

I want to call oracle forms from JavaScript by post method. i tried this solution:
[Read POST data from Oracle Forms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390278/read-post-data-from-oracle-forms-app/35886232#35886232][1])

And its work, but my "form" read just the first parameter and it's value is all data after the equal sign (=). it's look like the plus sign (+) didn't separate between the parameters.

Do you know what is the right separate sign that should i use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call Oracle Forms from a REST service, first you have to create a web service that is representing the actions that you want to perform on the Form.

The only way possible to do it, is by using a tool called AuraPlayer.
if you are not going to use that tool, you would have to implement the business logic behind the Form, and create a web service from it.

using AuraPlayer you can define the process on the form, and define the input/output parameters of the REST/SOAP service very easily (just in GUI)

Comment: Your profile shows that you are "CTO & Co-Founder at AuraPlayer", and right now you are saying that the only way to do something is to use that tool. While this might be true, your affiliation should be clearly disclosed in the answer, not only in your profile, otherwise it can be considered as advertisement and spam. So please [edit] your answer and explain it. Thank you!